# Hide access token displayed in url in address bar after login in using google

Tags: javascript, html, browser, google-oauth

I have built my app so that you can log in using Google. But when i redirect the user to the home page after logging in i can see the access token in the address bar of browser.It is being displayed after the URL of the page. Any suggestions how can i hide it? I prefer to do it in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be something like the following.

```
<script>
    location.href = location.origin + location.pathname;
</script>
```

This will redirect the browser from `https://example.com/foo/bar?access_token=xyz` to `https://example.com/foo/bar`.

- `location.origin` is `https://example.com`
- `location.pathname` is `/foo/bar`

[MDN docs for location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location)

Comment: can you give an example please

Comment: What is origin and pathname here

Comment: Clarified some details. `location` is a JS API you should really familorize yourself with.